# How to show that h is constant by using **Liouville's theorem**

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $h$ be an entire function.

$\exists$ some $R \gt 0$ and $z_0\in \Bbb C$ s.t. open ball $B_R(z_0)$ isnt in the range of $h$. $B_R(z_0)\cap h(\Bbb C) \not = \emptyset{}{}$

How to show that h is constant by using **Liouville's theorem**

I dont have any idea to prove this. Honestly, I would like to write but I cannot. Please help me. In fact, really, this question seems so difficult, so I asked. Thank you.

Comment: Compose $h$ with a suitable Möbius transformation.

Comment: The hint and the answer you have been given for the question are both good.  After receiving them, perhaps you should stop to think for more than three or four minutes before asking to be spoon-fed further explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $g(z)=1/(h(z)-z_0)$. $g$ is obviously entire, and your condition for the range of $h$ gives you that for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$ you have
$$|g(z)|=\frac{1}{|h(z)-z_0|}\leq \frac1R,$$
hence $g$ is bounded. Liouville's theorem now tells us that $g$ is constant, and so the same must be true for $h$.

Comment: Please can you clearly explain it? I cannot do sufficiently good. By the theorem, how did you reach the result?