# Showing $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is an entire function and that there is a nonempty open ball $B(w_0,r)$ such that $w\notin \mathrm{Range}(f)$ for all $w\in B(w_0,r)$. Show that $f$ is constant.

I'm not sure how to start this. This looks like maybe something to do with Liouville's Theorem, but this is under a topic where we try not to apply other theorems, so I'm not sure if I can use it here if it's even possible.

Comment: What can you say about $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)-w_0}$?

Comment: I think this is entire as well, or at least holomorphic since $w_0 \notin \mathrm{Range}(f)$?

Comment: Two words: Casorati-Weierstrass

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show that h is constant by using \*\*Liouville's theorem\*\*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582130/how-to-show-that-h-is-constant-by-using-liouvilles-theorem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $|f(z)-w_{0}| \geq r>0$, and in particular, and hence $\frac{1}{f(z)-w_{0}}$ is entire, and bounded by $\frac{1}{r}$ (above), and hence...

Comment: Cool!! $|f(z)-w_0|\geq r$ because $\mathrm{Range}(f)\notin B(w_0,r)$ right?

Comment: that's exactly it!

Comment: Thank you to you and Jose